# Java Knights Walk Algorithm (Brute Force)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write a [Knights Walk Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour)(brute force) using Java. I was able to create a program to move through a 5x5 grid but the program always leaves out 06 cells out of the board. And my Knight is unable to move anywhere from those squares as well.

For Example I have the following grid :

```
----------------
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1

a2,b2,c2,d2,e2

a3,b3,c3,d3,e3

a4,b4,c4,d4,e4

a5,b5,c5,d5,e5

----------------
```

and my algorithm prints out the following path and the cells visited

```
a1 -> b3
b3 -> c5
c5 -> a4
a4 -> c3
c3 -> d5
d5 -> b4
b4 -> a2
a2 -> c1
c1 -> d3
d3 -> e5
e5 -> c4
c4 -> a3
a3 -> b5
b5 -> d4
d4 -> c2
c2 -> e3
e3 -> d1
d1 -> b2

Cells Visited : [a1, b3, c5, a4, c3, d5, b4, a2, c1, d3, e5, c4, a3, b5, d4, c2, e3, d1, b2, b2, b2, b2, b2, b2, b2]
```

and as you can see the grid still has the following six cells untouched (x marks visited).

```
----------------
 x,b1,x,x,e1

 x,x,x,d2,e2

 x,x,x,x,x

 x,x,x,x,e4

 a5,x,x,x,x
```

---

this makes the following 6 cells :

```
 b1,e1,d2,e2,e4,a5
```

remain untouched and I can't seem to move to any other cell from these cells as well.

Could anyone please point out what I may be doing wrong ?. I have given my code below :

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


  public class KnightsWalk {

String[] colnames   = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f","g","h"};
String[] rownumbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8"};

static final int gridSize = 5; //Specify the grid size here
static String grid[][] = new String[gridSize][gridSize];
static int[][] moves = {{2, 1},{1, 2},{-1,-2},{-2,-1},{2,-1},{-2,1},{-1,2},{1,-2}};//All Possible Moves

//Visited Cells
static List<String> visitedCells = new ArrayList<>();


private void initGrid() {

    if (gridSize>=3 || gridSize<=8) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
                grid[row][col] = colnames[col] + rownumbers[row];
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Grid Size of "+gridSize+" is Not Supported ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private boolean canMoveToCell(int[] cellvisiting) {
    try{
    //check if the  cell visiting has been visited before
    String cell = grid[cellvisiting[0]][cellvisiting[1]];
    boolean canmove = !visitedCells.contains(cell);
    return canmove;
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        return false;
    }
}

private void walk(int cell[]) {

    String start = grid[cell[0]][cell[1]];
    visitedCells.add(start); //Add the starting cell to already visited


    if(visitedCells.size() == (gridSize*gridSize)){
        return;
    }

    int[] nextCellToMoveto = null;
    for(int[] move:moves){
       int[] nc1 = { cell[0]+move[0], cell[1]+move[1] }; 
        if (canMoveToCell(nc1)) {
            printMove(cell, nc1);
            nextCellToMoveto=nc1;
            break;
        }
        else{ 
            int[] nc2 = { cell[0]+move[1], cell[1]+move[0] }; 
            if(canMoveToCell(nc2)){
                printMove(cell, nc2);
                nextCellToMoveto=nc2;
                break;
            }
            else{
                nextCellToMoveto=cell;
            }  
        }
    }
    walk(nextCellToMoveto); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KnightsWalk gw = new KnightsWalk();
    gw.initGrid();
    gw.printGrid();
   for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
               int startingcell [] = {row,col};
               System.out.println("Cells Visited : "+visitedCells);
                visitedCells.clear();//Clearing the Previous cells visited when hit a dead end
                gw.walk(startingcell);
                System.out.println("Trying with Starting Cell : "+grid[startingcell[0]][startingcell[1]]);
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Cells Visited : "+visitedCells);
}

/** 
 * Auxiliary Support Methods for user output support 
 */
private void printMove(int[] start, int[] end) {
    System.out.println(grid[start[0]][start[1]] + " -> " + grid[end[0]][end[1]]);
}

private void printGrid() {
    System.out.println("----------------");
    for (String[] row : grid) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
            String sep = (col < grid.length - 1) ? "," : "";
            System.out.print(row[col] + sep);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("----------------");
}
 }
```

***Update 3 the Code Now it prints the solution as follows :***

```
----------------
 a1,a2,a3,a4,a5

 b1,b2,b3,b4,b5

 c1,c2,c3,c4,c5

 d1,d2,d3,d4,d5

 e1,e2,e3,e4,e5

----------------

25 of out 25 Cells Visited in the order [a1, c2, a3, b1, d2, e4, c3, b5, d4, e2, c1, a2, b4, d5, e3, d1, b2, a4, c5, b3, a5, c4, e5, d3, e1]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The Updated Code is As Below :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


 public class KnightsWalk {

String[] rownames = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};
String[] colnames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};

static final int gridSize = 5; //Specify the grid size here
static String grid[][];
static int[][] moves = {{-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, 2}};//All Possible Moves
static List<String> visitedCells = new ArrayList<>(); //Visited Cells

int numberOfMoves = 0;


private void initGrid() {

    if (gridSize >= 3 && gridSize <= 8) {
        grid = new String[gridSize][gridSize];
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String[] gridrow : grid) {
            for (int cell = 0; cell < gridrow.length; cell++) {
                gridrow[cell] = rownames[rownum] + colnames[cell];
            }
            rownum += 1;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Grid Size of " + gridSize + " is Not Supported ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private boolean canWalkToCell(int[] cellvisiting) {

    //check if the  cell visiting has been visited before
    try {
        //Method chained to return if the cell is in the list
        String cell = grid[cellvisiting[0]][cellvisiting[1]];
        if(visitedCells.contains(cell)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        //This is the lazy way to check if the coordinates are in the grid
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean walk(int cell[]) {

    String nextCell = grid[cell[0]][cell[1]];
    visitedCells.add(nextCell); //Add the starting cell to already visited
    numberOfMoves += 1;

    if (numberOfMoves == (gridSize * gridSize)) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int[] move : moves) {

        int[] nc = {cell[0] + move[0], cell[1] + move[1]};

        if (canWalkToCell(nc)) {   

            if(walk(nc)){
                return true;
            }            
        }

    }

    //Backtracking
    numberOfMoves -= 1;
    visitedCells.remove(nextCell);
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KnightsWalk gw = new KnightsWalk();
    gw.initGrid();
    gw.printGrid();
    int startingcell[] = {0, 0};
    gw.walk(startingcell);

    System.out.println("" + visitedCells.size() + " of out " + (gridSize * gridSize) + " Cells Visited in the order " + visitedCells);
}

/**
 * Auxiliary Support Methods for user output support
 */
private void printAtteptedMove(int[] start, int[] end) {
    System.out.println(grid[start[0]][start[1]] + " -> " + grid[end[0]][end[1]]);
}

private void printGrid() {

    System.out.println("----------------");
    for (String[] gridrow : grid) {
        for (int cell = 0; cell < gridrow.length; cell++) {
            String sep = (cell < gridrow.length - 1) ? "," : "";
            System.out.print(gridrow[cell] + sep);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("----------------");
}
 }
```

Comment: That is not "brute-force". You only go forward looking for possible moves, but never "delete" them if they get you into an unsolvable state. Google for "backtracking algorithms"

Comment: Brute force algorithms remind me of a man taking down a wall with a sledgehammer because he doesn't like the paint color, and for good reason. Brute force algorithms literally try EVERY possibility until one of them works, comparable to throwing a deck of cards in the air, picking it up, and if it isn't completely in order, throw it again. (The basis behind bogosort as a matter of fact.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that it is not a real brute force algorithm. You just start running until nothing is possible. for a brute force algorithm you would have to try every other possibility for moves too, not just those starting with a1->b3->c5
try recursive functions for brute force

also i dont see why you need the following code, when your moves list (for a single move) is complete.

```
else{ 
    int[] nc2 = { cell[0]+move[1], cell[1]+move[0] }; 
    if(canMoveToCell(nc2)){
        printMove(cell, nc2);
        nextCellToMoveto=nc2;
        break;
    }
    else{
        nextCellToMoveto=cell;
    }
```

update:
there is still a mistake in the updated version of the OP. if you try a new path it should forget the old one in "visitedcells". So what you have to do is the following: after your for loop in the function "walk", remove the element from your list "visitedCells.
Your mistake can be seen here in the output:

```
[...]
h2 -> f1
b6 -> a8
f2 -> h1
```

thats not how it should look like i guess

Comment: @user1648962 your welcome, and thx for correcting. i updated my post now, because i think i found another mistake

Comment: @user1648962 i think its not a good idea to have printAtteptedMove inside the function walk, because you might print stuff that does not belong to the final solution.
i would suggest to have a return value for the function "walk", (boolean or int), with "true" for a path where you found a successful solution. this way you could also stop looking for other possibilities if you found a solution to save time

Comment: Finally !!!. I did that and it works like a charm. thank you so much for your help. This was a great exercise for me to cut the rust off my brain.  Now I will continue to optimize it for a 8*8.